# What is the better way to cancel a ngrx effect service call, based on a validation in the effect?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have this ngrx effect that is calling in this example to movies service, but is depending of a value selector, if this values is as expected in validation, the effect sould send a new action, this way I avoid to call the service because the condition. Right now I cannot use another action (this would be more descriptive) in the *if* block because of this error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable | ((...args: any[]) => Observable)'.
>
> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.ts(2322).

What is the better way to handle this scenario?

```
loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
        concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getBlockBuster)))),
        mergeMap(([{payload}, foundBlockBuster]) => {
            if (!foundBlockBuster) {
                // in order to avoid errors we need to use this({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies }))
                return of({ type: '[Movies] The block busters are rent' })
            }
            return this.moviesService.getAll()
                .pipe(
                    map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
                    catchError(() => of({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Error' }))
                )
            })
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because you should return `Observable<action>` instead your code is returning two types of object literal (assumed as it is of type `Action`) one which has only `type` property and another one has `type` and `payload`. To fix this error have an array of `Action` and then push your object literal in that array and then return that array like this:

```
loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
        concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getBlockBuster)))),
        mergeMap(([{payload}, foundBlockBuster]) => {

            const actions = new Array<Action>();

            if (!foundBlockBuster) {
                actions.push({ type: '[Movies] The block busters are rent' });
                return actions;                
            }
            return this.moviesService.getAll()
                .pipe(
                    mergeMap(movies => {
                      actions.push({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies });
                      return actions;
                    }),
                    catchError(() => {
                      actions.push({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Error' });
                      return actions;
                    })
                )
            })
        )
    );
```

Alternatively, you can typecast your object literals as `<Action>` like this:

```
<Action>{ type: '[Movies] The block busters are rent' }
```

But I prefer to use the array as array allows to dispatch multiple actions if my app logic needs so.

Hope it helps.